# Open Downloads folder on Pixel C

Tags: android, android-intent, android-download-manager, android-8.1-oreo

I am trying to open Downloads folder via intent. Here's the line that opens it.

```
startActivity(new Intent(DownloadManager.ACTION_VIEW_DOWNLOADS));
```

This code opens default Downloads folder on all devices except Pixel C (running Android 8.1). On Pixel C, it opens Documents folder by default. Any idea about this change in behaviour?

There is no Downloads folder as such on Pixel C, it has been moved into Files app. How can I get this working on Pixel C? Any ideas?

Comment: `it has been moved into Files. ` ??? Whats FIles?

Comment: Android 8.0 introduced own file manager app, Files. You can view downloads from Files app